# Avoiding race condition with continuous deployment into virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, devops

My colleagues don't want to create their own virtualenv and deploy my tools from git on their own as part of their automation. Instead they want the tools pre installed on a shared server.

So I was thinking of making a /opt directory, putting the virtualenv in there and then pulling from git every hour to force an update of the python package. I am not version tagging the tools currently and instead would just ask pip to force the update every time.

The problem is the race condition. If the tool is called by their automation during the pip upgrade, the tool can fail due to the install not being atomic - I believe pip removes the entire package first.

I've thought of various work arounds (forcing the use of flock, using symlink to atomically switch the virtualenv, wrapping the tool in a script that makes the virtualenv in a temp directory for every use...)

Is there a best practice here I'm not aware of?

edit: I also asked over at [devops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/10851/continuous-deployment-of-package-to-virtualenv/10879#10879) and got a pretty good answer.

Comment: Modern practices lean heavily towards using containers for deployment, but other methods are still viable.

Comment: maybe use a lock file?

Comment: Mmm... not a bad idea, @pkqxdd !   Each script does a read lock when running and the update process applies a write lock ... but I’d need to put these in shell wrappers outside the virtual env.